# What am I doing wrong in this semantic tableux?

Tags: logic

[image: The question]

[image: The rules]

Alright, so I'm trying to prove that it follows logically from the premise using semantic tableux. The solution is that it doesn't follow logically but every time I do it my solution says that it does. I've provided a pic of the question, the rules and my solution. reg. stands for rule and is my way of showing what rules I have applied. [image: My solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leftmost branch.

After $\lnot C$, you have to "unpack" $C \to (A \lor B)$ with rule 3 (for $\lor$) generating two branches.

The left one has $C$ and it is closed.

The right one has $(A \to B)$ which obviously is open.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I first applied rule 9 on the second statement and got the two branches, ¬C and ¬(¬AvB). I then applied rule 6 on ¬(¬AvB) and got A & ¬B which I had to put in both branches.

Comment: @MogulKhan - But $\lnot(\lnot A \lor B)$ is only on the right branch; thus, rule 6 must be applied only to it and **not** also to the left branch.

Comment: .. Oh. I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: @MogulKhan - you are welcome :-)